# Using Renovate in Kubernetes like Docker-Compose's Watchtower

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, docker-watchtower, renovate

While looking for a kubernetes equivalent of the docker-compose watchtower container, I stumbled upon renovate. It seems to be a universal tool to update docker tags, dependencies and more.

They also have an [example](https://docs.renovatebot.com/examples/self-hosting/#kubernetes) of how to run the service itself inside kubernetes, and I found this [blogpost](https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/automated-dependency-updates-for-kubernetes-manifests/) of how to set renovate up to check kubernetes manifests for updates (?).

Now the puzzle piece that I'm missing is some super basic working example that updates a single pod's image tag, and then figuring out how to deploy that in a kubernetes cluster. I feel like there needs to be an example out there somewhere but I can't find it for the life of me.

To explain watchtower:
It monitors all containers running in a docker compose setup and pulls new versions of images once they are available, updating the containers in the process.

Answer (score 2):

I found one **[keel](https://keel.sh/)** which looks like watchtower:

> Kubernetes Operator to automate Helm, DaemonSet, StatefulSet & Deployment updates

Alternatively, there is **[duin](https://crazymax.dev/diun/providers/kubernetes/)**

> Docker Image Update Notifier is a CLI application written in Go and delivered as a single executable (and a Docker image) to receive notifications when a Docker image is updated on a Docker registry.

> The Kubernetes provider allows you to analyze the pods of your Kubernetes cluster to extract images found and check for updates on the registry.

Comment: this sounds great, but since neither you nor I have tried it, I'm hesitant to give it the right answer check

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion regarding what Renovate does.

Renovate updates files inside GIT repositories not on the Kubernetes API server.
The Kubernetes manager which you are probably referencing updates K8 manifests, Helm charts and so on inside of GIT repository.